# Getting a really high chi-squared value, is there an issue with my the sample used or how I calculated the chi-sqaured value?

Tags: excel

I'm getting a really high chi-squared value, is there an issue with my the sample used or how I calculated the chi-sqaured value?

I used this site to calulate my chisqaured value - https://datatab.net/statistics-calculator/hypothesis-test/chi-square_test_calculator

Data - has age groups and type of coffee they prefer (the numbers in the cells are the number of people that prefer that coffee according to the age group ). 
***This was the data used to calculate the chi-squared values***
[image: This was the data used to calculate the chi-squared values]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I did calculate the chisquared value and I got a value of 200 and a p value of less than 0.05